# How to use Generics in Kotlin extension function

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, kotlin-android-extensions

I had 2 functions that does basically the same thing, so I thought to create an extension function.

The problem is that I need to extract the data of each class in order to get the correct result, I thought of creating a Generic function, and inside this function decide which class member to access inside `when` statement.

But when I try to call `T` inside the when statement, I'm getting `Type parameter 'T' is not an expression`

What am I doing wrong?

**My function:**

```
fun <T: Any> List<T>.extractWithSepreation(errorString: String): String {
    var errorString = "There is no available $errorString"

    if (this.isEmpty()) {
        return errorString
    }
    
    errorString = ""
    this.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        when(T)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message pretty much says it all. `T` is not an expression, so it cannot be used inside `when(...)`. `T` just refers to the class of the `item` of the `List`.

Didn't you mean using something like:

```
when(item) {
   is ClassA -> doSomething()
   is ClassB -> doSomethingElse()
}
```

?

Comment: Actually this exactly what I meant, I was so after the T thing that I didn't even think about the simplest solution

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you @Masksway